# .svg image that contain text, font-family missing in Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg

I have .svg image and some text inside with custom font, I am using this image in my css, this is div "background"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8EL6.png

On Chrome and Safary this image works fine, but in Mozilla I have different font, for some reason font replaced by another font

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUrot.png

Can it be fixed somehow? where is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data in an SVG file when used as an image must be in a single file. If you've referenced a downloadable font as something like this...

```
src: url('http://example.com/fonts/font.otf');
```

Then you must convert that to a data URL e.g.

```
src: url("data:font/opentype;base64,[base64-encoded font here]");
```

So that all the data is in the one file.